# Maven NatTable clean+install failure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho, nattable

I'm trying to import and resolve the developer projects for the **NatTable** project as explained in their [Getting Started](http://eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=getting_started) tutorial.

I'm getting the following error on `mvn -f [path to pom] clean install`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession.getRepositorySession()Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystemSession;

More details:

- `mvn --version` works fine
- `%MAVEN_HOME%` points to [devel]/maven-3.1.0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The NatTable project seems to have configured the Tycho build extension in a version which is not compatible with Maven 3.1.

Either ask the project to switch to a Tycho version which works with Maven 3.1 (0.18.1 or later), or downgrade your local Maven installation to 3.0.5.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how did you figure that out?

Comment: I happen to be committer on the Tycho project, and we've been [notified from the Maven guys](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=406056) about the changes of some internals in Maven 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

The NatTable project recently updated to use Maven Tycho 0.19.0.

Thanks for the hint.